# Do vectors uniquely determine their spectral measures?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $\mathscr{H}$ be a Hilbert space, $\psi \in \mathscr{H}$ and $A$ be a densely-defined self-adjoint operator. From the Borel functional calculus, for each measurable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, there exists a bounded linear operator $f(A)$ on $\mathscr{H}$. For each bounded continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$, define:
$$\omega(f) = \langle \psi, f(A)\psi\rangle$$
This is a positive linear functional, so by Riesz-Markov Theorem there exists a Borel measure $\mu_{\psi}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$\langle \psi, f(A)\psi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)d\mu_{\psi}(x).$$

**Question:** Suppose $\mu_{\psi} = \mu_{\varphi}$. Is it true that $\psi = \varphi$? I could not conclude this from $\langle \psi,f(A)\rangle = \langle \varphi,f(A)\varphi\rangle$.

Comment: What about $\psi = - \varphi$?

Comment: You mean taking $f= -1$?

Comment: No, prior to apply Riesz-Markov theorem try to see what happens when $\psi = - \varphi$

Comment: Perhaps you should reformulate: are these vectors linearly dependent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is not true even for two-dimensional space with orthonormal basis $e_1,e_2$ and the identity operator. Then the measures corresponding to $e_1$ and $e_2$ are equal, although the vectors are linearly independent. I guess the conclusion may hold for operators with simple spectrum